# SELECT query in chunks using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, perl

I have a table with well over a million entries. I'm putting all this data into perl and storing it into a variable ($query = "SELECT * FROM table1". The problem now is that I'm using a lot of resources (mostly memory). Given my novice state with perl and postgres, How would I transform that query into chunks or parts?

For example,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT 100000";
```

Would put 100K results into $query. table1 is 10M records in size. How would I transform it so that only 100K results are stored into $query at a time until the query is finished?

Comment: What are you doing with retrieved data?

Comment: I check the retrieved data to make sure its valid, if it is, it stays in the table. If it is invalid, it is marked as invalid with an update (as it may become valid at another time).

Comment: Then you retrieve it in a loop like this `while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
   # Do validation stuff on @row
   # Mark If invalid
}`, It will handle any number of rows in DB.

Comment: Also look into this Perl monk discussion [Speeding up the DBI](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=273952), This will answer your concerns.

Comment: You appear to know about the `LIMIT` criterion. Combining that with `OFFSET` seems to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all do you really need all 10M records? don't think so and thus retrieve only the records for your work to be done. Second, do you really need all columns data? may not be and in such case select only the columns needed saying `select col1, col2, col3 ... from table` instead of doing a `select *...`. Cause, there is no point in getting all data and filling your server's memory.

In worst case, if what you have said is what you actually in need then you have no other way than retrieving all records. You can probably implement paging to get data in batches rather than getting all of them at once.

Comment: I do need all 10M records! I run a test against each one of them, so it takes a while. However, I do not need *every* column. So, my query would really need to look like this: "SELECT col1, col2 FROM table" along with all the entries. Now, couldn't I retrieve it in chunks using rows, by selecting the row count and storing that in the QUERY and then building it so that it will grab the results in row chunks until completed?

Answer (score 0):

Pagination?

Maybe this might be of use:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/queries-limit.html

Sorry if I have misunderstood.

Comment: Is there no way to store the data in 100K chunks by selecting lets say row 0 to row 100K, then 101K to  200K, Then 201K to 300K, up to the end (10M)?

Comment: I suppose I can do what I'm asking by creating an id sequence, and then just selecting chunks that way. I have no other ideas on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Trick :

you can use **modulus** for chunk data

**e.g :**

you want chunk data from 1000 record, chunk data 4 pieces using seq id
you just modulus seq id data 4,

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM input_data_control b
 WHERE  b.bill_schedule_month = '201910' 
        AND mod(input_data_control_id, 4) = [1...4]
```